# Yii 2 - using custom helpers

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to use a custom helper class which i create under `frontend/components/Helper` (Helper.php)

The content of that file is something like:

```
<?php
namespace frontend\components\Helper;

class Helper {

    public static function helperGreetings() {
        echo("hello helper");
    }
}
?>
```

and on my SiteController.php i have the following:

```
use frontend\components\Helper;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        Helper::helperGreetings();
        return $this->render('index');
    }
}
```

What should i do to have it working?

BTW, the error i get is Unknown Class – yii\base\UnknownClassException

```
Unable to find 'frontend\components\Helper' in file: /Users/foo/sites/bar.dev/frontend/components/Helper.php. Namespace missing?
```

Comment: I think you don't see the result  because rhe return $this->render('index');  override your echo. Try Using Helper inside the rendered view

Comment: No, same error: (Unknown Class – yii\base\UnknownClassException)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the namespace in the Helper class from

```
namespace frontend\components\Helper;
```

to

```
namespace frontend\components;
```